# iOS: building a static library from c++ code fails

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, static-libraries

I have been trying to create an static library out of C++ code by following [this tutorial](http://blog.andolasoft.com/2013/11/how-to-create-a-static-library-or-framework-for-ios.html). If I trying to build the project some error occurs.

```
#include <limits>  "limits" file not found
```

for example.

I have been trying different build settings, e.g. C++ Standard Library  with no luck. 
Rename the implementation files from .cpp to .mm did not work also. Is there an workaround to solve this issues?

Comment: Somewhere, depending on your compiler, you need to tell it where to find the standard library include paths. Refer to its documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `#include <limits.h>` instead of `#include <limits>`